# What happens behind the scene when i write for loop like this

Tags: java, jpa, for-loop

I wondering what compiler is doing behind the scene when i write the `for loop` like this

1.

```
for(ChildObject child : parentObject.getChildObjects()){
     //do something
}
```

instead of

2.

```
List<ChildObject> myList = parentObject.getChildObjects();
for(ChildObject child : myList){
     //do something
}
```

Statement `parentObject.getChildObjects()` is a JPA statement, and the fetch type is LAZY.

**NOTE**: I have read the java doc of `for-each` loop (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), however they have not mentioned a case like above.

So i know how the loop works, but do not know what is happening to the list returned from the `parentObject.getChildObjects()` statement.

**My doubts:**

1. In the first case is compiler saving the list returned from `parentObject.getChildObjects()` statement in some temp variable, which is hidden from the programmer or it is calling the statement every time?
2. If it is calling the statement `parentObject.getChildObjects()`, every time; How is it keeping track of the next elements?

Comment: Use `javap` to decompile your class to see the difference.

Comment: You have read a *guide.* Try the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2). It answers this question completely.

Comment: @EJP Or just a [better guide](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with).

Comment: @biziclop thanks for the better guide... now its clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What dit has mentioned, is what exactly happening behind the scene. Just to add to his answer:

In both `case 1 & 2` compiler will create an `iterator` and save it.

The difference between the two approaches is:

**Case 1:**

the `for loop` will transform to

```
for(Iterator<ChildObject> it = parentObject.getChildObjects.iterator; it.hasNext();){

}
```

**NOTE:** `parentObject.getChildObjects`, returns a `List` which implements `Iterable` interface. Neither `ParentObject` nor `ChildObject` implements `Iterable`.

This is important to know as in "dit's" example, his class is implementing the Iterable interface.

> On Stack: only `Iterator` is saved.

**Case 2:**

the `for loop` will transform to

```
List<ChildObject> myList = parentObject.getChildObjects;
for(Iterator<ChildObject> it = myList.iterator; it.hasNext();){

}
```

> On Stack: `iterator` is saved and `myList` is saved.

**Conclusion:**

Case 1 is better than 2 if `memory usage` is considered, otherwise both approaches are same.

Answer (score 2):

For-Each Loop is working with all classes that implement [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) - interface, cause it needs `iterator()` - operation to transform your for-each syntax into iterator loop:

```
public class ChildObject {
    [...]
}

public class ParentObject implements Iterable<ChildObject> {

    private List<ChildObject> childObjects;

    [...]

    @Override
    public Iterator<ChildObject> iterator() {
        return childObjects.iterator();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    ParentObject p = new ParentObject();

    [...]

    for(ChildObject child : p){
        System.out.println(child);
    }

}
```

So

```
for(ChildObject child : p)
```

will be transformed into:

```
for(Iterator<ChildObject> it = p.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    ChildObject child = it.next();
    [...]
}
```

Thats why it doesn't matter how you code your fore-each loop.

P.S. if you iterate over an primitive Array like `int[] array`, compiler will transform your code into simple *iterate over array* loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
```

For more information check the comments to your question.

Comment: Just to be clear.. what you meant is my statement `parentObject.getChildObjects()` is converted to `Iterator<childObject> it = parentObject.getChildObjects().iterator` ?... So in short we are saving the iterator and not the entire list... Therefore can i say approach 1 is better than 2, if we consider memory usage?

Comment: iterator is just a wrapper for your list. approaches 1 and 2 are equal. In both cases compiler will call `list.iterator()`.

Comment: Yes, it will call `list.iterator`, however niether I nor compiler is saving the list in temp variable in case 1.. hence making case 1 to use less `stack memory` as compared case 2..

Comment: Yes, you will save the `reference size` (32 or 64 bit) but I'm pretty sure the compiler will optimize the code and remove the unnecessary reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since issues such as memory usage have been touched, I think it's worth mentioning that in practice it is unlikely you will ever notice the difference, since the extra `astore` and `aload` instructions that the compiler might put in will mostly be optimised away at runtime.

The difference that matters is that with case 2 you can accidentally do something like this:

```
List<ChildObject> myList = parentObject.getChildObjects;
for(Iterator<ChildObject> it = myList.iterator; it.hasNext();){
    ...
}
...
ChildObject ob = myList.get(0);
```

Now this isn't something that you should be doing and that's why case 1 is almost always preferred. More on this can be read under item 45 (Minimize the scope of local variables) in the second edition of Effective Java.